# String center-align in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, text-alignment, center-align

How can I make center-align in the following poem using python

"She Walks in Beauty
BY LORD BYRON (GEORGE GORDON)
She walks in beauty, like the night
Of cloudless climes and starry skies;
And all that’s best of dark and bright
Meet in her aspect and her eyes;
Thus mellowed to that tender light
Which heaven to gaudy day denies."

```py
x = "She Walks in Beauty\nBY LORD BYRON (GEORGE GORDON)\nShe walks in beauty, like the night\nOf cloudless climes and starry skies;\nAnd all that’s best of dark and bright\nMeet in her aspect and her eyes;\nThus mellowed to that tender light\nWhich heaven to gaudy day denies."

a = x.center(20, " ")

print(a)
```

I tried, but its not working. I try to make it center-align which will be depend on device size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Split the line into individual lines using `splitlines()`.
2. Find the size of your terminal with [`os.get_terminal_size()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.get_terminal_size).
3. Iterate though lines and print the lines using `.center()` and pass `column` size.

```py
import os

column, row = os.get_terminal_size()
x = "She Walks in Beauty\nBY LORD BYRON (GEORGE GORDON)\nShe walks in beauty, like the night\nOf cloudless climes and starry skies;\nAnd all that’s best of dark and bright\nMeet in her aspect and her eyes;\nThus mellowed to that tender light\nWhich heaven to gaudy day denies."
lines = x.splitlines()
for line in lines:
    print(line.center(column))
```